# Xcode IDE 6.3.2 slowdown and Crashes when programming in Swift in Playgrounds

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Xcode slowdown and Crashes

I am currently learning Swift using the playground in Xcode, but every few minutes I get a multi-colored progress bar which renders Xcode unusable. I then have to restart Xcode which causes me to lose unsaved data. It's really terrible and causing me a lot of stress. Any suggestions or tips to solve this?

Comment: Can you paste an example of code that you're testing out that freezes? It executes live, so if it enters infinite recursion, it may freeze.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to **reinstall** your Xcode, but if that does not fix any the problem, it might be the error in the log then, I'm assuming that your code is causing the crash, not Xcode. Can you paste the code from the playground it's crashing on.

Comment: //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
//lists
var str = "Hello, playground"
println("List: \n\tBread\n\tWaffles\n\tCereal")
println("List:\n \t apples \n \t oranges \n \t watermelon \n \t grapes")
println("List: \n \t PC \n \t ChromeBook \n \t Mac")
//arrays, dictionaries
var gameOver = !false
var gameSet = 3
var gameRematch = -gameSet
var gameRemat = ++gameSet
var gameRemat2 = --gameSet
var array = ["Tomato", "Grapes", "Watermelon", "Apples", "Pineapple"]
array.count
array.append("apricot")
array [0] = "Pears"
array [1]

Comment: The code is fine, there is something up with your xcode, did you try reinstalling it?